# VBA Workbook_Open not working on opening

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with the below code. Firstly it does not seem to run when I open up the workbook.

My second issue is that when I run this code through the VBA manually (as in F8). When it gets to the Listindex/Listcount command it falls over as it goes off trying to run a separate piece of code based on the user's selection in the combobox. Which is because it's trying to run the variable 'Select Server' which is obviously not a server. But on opening the workbook I don't want it to run anything I just want the neat instruction to 'Select Server'.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

With Application
    '.Calculation = xlManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

        Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Server.AddItem "Select Server"
        Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Server.AddItem "UK-SQL-Z001"
        Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Server.AddItem "UK-SQL-z002"
        Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Server.ListIndex = Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Server.ListCount - 3


        Sheets("Data Summary").CB_DB.AddItem "Select DB"
        Sheets("Data Summary").CB_DB.ListIndex = Sheets("Data Summary").CB_DB.ListCount - 1

        With Sheets("Data Summary").CB_Portfolio
        .AddItem
        .List(0, 0) = "Select Portfolio"
        .List(0, 1) = "Select Portfolio"
        End With

        Sheets("Data Summary").CB_CCY.AddItem "GBP"
        Sheets("Data Summary").CB_CCY.AddItem "EUR"
        Sheets("Data Summary").CB_CCY.AddItem "USD"
        Sheets("Data Summary").CB_CCY.ListIndex = Sheets("Data Summary").CB_CCY.ListCount - 3

Sheets("Data Summary").Range("D11:H23").Cells.ClearContents

Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("B2:G10").Cells.ClearContents

'Restore the settings.
With Application
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong! Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is this code? Is it in `ThisWorkbook`? Because it won't run on open unless it is...

Comment: Yes its saved in the ThisWorkBook object

Comment: I have no problem running a simple sub that just pops up MsgBox when file opens. If you want to provide file for analysis I recommend Box.com fileshare site. And if you don't want this code to run on open then why is it even in that procedure?

Comment: That's the thing its not in this procedure, the workbook open macro somehow jumps to another macro in one of the worksheets (that's not even referenced in the workbook open macro) and tries to reach out to SQL and falls over?